# Using a web service to perform INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE queries, having a bit of trouble

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I am trying to follow this tutorial but I am having a few problems with it, the connection in step 6:

```
private string ()
{
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["collegedatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        return conString;
}
```

Doesn't work, the code returns an error at `return conString;` this line, saying

> invalid token return
>   'CollegeSystemWebsite.Service.conString' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

How would I go about connecting?

This is my `web.config` connection string

```
connectionStrings>
        <add name="collegedatabaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=COOM-3015-pc19\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=collegedatabase;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/99832454-6f3e-403d-87c5-6c1c5d0a1ebc/?Insert,%20Delete,%20Update%20in%20SQL%20using%20web%20service%20in%20ASP.NET

Comment: It seems like you have a method without a name .... try using `public string SomeMethodName() { ... }`

Comment: As @marc_s said, you have a broken method definition. This has nothing to do with SQL or web services

Answer (score 0):

add reference System.Configuration and then

```
 string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["collegedatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

As @marc_s already answererd in a comment, your code is broken. You forgot to define the method name in `private string ()`. You should define a proper method like

```
private string GetTheString()
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["collegedatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    return conString;
}
```

As for why you get this error,the C# compiler doesn't understand what you are trying to do and seems to think you are trying to define a malformed private nested class called `string`, in which case conString is a field of this (malformed) type and can't be returned.

I suspect you have other issues in the code surrounding the sample, because the compiler would generate completely different errors if a missing method name was the only problem. You probably have a broken class declaration as well.

What does the *rest* of the code look like?